# '[Any?]' is not convertible to 'Anyobject?'

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

i found this error in this line : if caching === nil  on my code:

```
struct  dataArray {
    var dataById = Dictionary<String, Any>()
}
```

---

```
var id :String?

func dataBegin() {
     let idString = id as String!
     let byCategory = [dataArray().dataById[idString]]

     if byCategory === nil {  //error:'[Any?]' is not convertible to 'Anyobject?'
     // some code
            }
}
```

Comment: What is the intent of that line? The `===` is the identity operator doesn't make sense unless both lhs and rhs are variables that point to object instances. Second, you just said that `byCategory` was an array, so it could never be `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

`===` is the identity operator, which is supposed to be used for checking if two references point to the same instance. You probably wanted to use `==` to check for nil.

However, the `byCategory` variable is initialized as a non optional array, and as such it cannot be nil, and consequently it cannot be checked for nil.

I think there's a mistake in the logic of that function.